# Where I can get NMEA data dump of GLONASS or GPS simulator?

Tags: data-request

For my graduation work and [my open source project](https://github.com/Dronnikkl/GNSS-spoofing-detection) about detection of «spoofing» GPS and GLONASS signal I need NMEA data dump of GPS/GLONASS receiver which receive signals from GLONASS or GPS simulator.

Where I can get NMEA logs which include $GPGSV strings? 
Because I analyze levels of satellites signal and try to detect «spoofing».

Answer (score 1):

You can get NMEA logs from this website: [FreeNMEA](http://freenmea.net/)

Actually, it does not provide real logs (until you uploaded them), but you can generate "synthetic" (random) logs for testing. e.g. you can generate logs with GSV sentences only.

Use this tool without registration: [NMEA emitter](http://freenmea.net/emitter) for generating random logs.
If you need to generate logs for GPS/GLONASS you need to log into website and you'll be able to select Talker IDs for your logs.